# Loading bar for iframe while reloading via location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, loading

I have an iframe which is refreshed at button press while reading from a kendo datepicker the information to decide what data needs to be loaded.
The iframe has an onlaod gif showing that it is still loading data at initialisation, which can take up to 20 seconds in this example.
The same loading bar I want to use while getting new data/refreshing the iframe. Any idea how to achieve this behaviour? Like calling onload again

```
<iframe id="iframeExample"
        frameborder="0"
        border="0"
        marginwidth="0"
        marginheight="0"
        style="border: none; margin-left: 10px; padding: 1px; margin-top: 5px; display: block;"
        height="500px"
        width="98%"
        runat="server"
        src='@Url.Action("Action","Controller", new { Id1= @Model.Id1, Id2 = @Model.Id2 })'
        onload="document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';"></iframe>
```

The image for the onload 
        `<div id="loadImg"><img id="image" src="~/Content/Kendo/2018.1.117/Bootstrap/loading-image.gif" /></div>`

and the following for refreshing the iframe

```
var ActionUrl = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { Id1 ="_PLACEHOLDER_ID1_", Id2= "_PLACEHOLDER_ID2_" }))";

function refreshIFrame() {
    debugger;
    var Id1= $("#Id1").val();
    var dtId2 = $("#Id1").getKendoDatePicker().value();
    var Id2 = kendo.toString(dtId2, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    document.getElementById("iframeExample").contentDocument.location.href = ActionUrl.replace("_PLACEHOLDER_ID1_", Id1).replace("_PLACEHOLDER_ID2_", Id2);
}
```

Thank you for any hints and tipps

Comment: Reverse what the onload handler does - and set the icon to `display:block` again in your function …?

Comment: document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display = 'block'; and after the location.href a document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display = 'none'; I tried if you mean that. The probblem ist that display = 'none' can happen before you have loaded the data from the Action